# How to "go deeper" than firebug/chrome dev tools net panel?

Tags: firefox, networking, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

How do I take a deeper look at what's going on in the network level of my web browser than the developer tools network panel will provide? For example, I'm trying to debug an issue on a page right now in Firefox (18.0.1) where the loading "spinner" keeps going continuously long after the page has finished loading.

The firebug net panel shows all resources loaded ("200 OK") but the loading icon on the tab is still spinning and the text on the bottom of the window still shows "Transferring data..". How would I take a closer look and see what is supposedly still transferring? Note that this only seems to happen with Firefox and only on a fresh load (not when resources are cached).

Comment: There aren't any outstanding network requests. This looks like a Firefox bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking your link with Wireshark and with HTTPScoup (a different tool), my conclusion from both was that all the data arrives successfully and no connection remains open with your server's IP. The problem in FF I think is related to something else

Google reveals that in some cases, it is possible to confuse FF into this state. It doesn't have to be related to open network connections.

Take a look at this questions for example:
[FireFox sits on "Transferring data from..." or "Read...."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304471/firefox-sits-on-transferring-data-from-or-read)

The issue there was unclosed tags in the HTML body.. so try to find problems like this one too. You can try fixing some validation errors by running a validator such as this [one](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dinolite.us%2Ffeatures%2Fpolarization&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Since you have about **200** validation errors, I suggest you start by deleting half your HTML code until the problem goes away and this way zero-in on the problem location. Then go in and fix the tag mess.. looking a little in the HTML source gave me a headache :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to do this.  Both of these tools provide more low level packet information.

I would start with Fiddler.  Fiddler is meant for http traffic analysis whereas Wireshark is a full-fledged packet sniffing tool for all layers of network traffic.

Another advantage to both of these tools is that you can use them with any browser. One disadvantage to fiddler is I believe it is only available for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried Fiddler first, but I am having the same problem I have with firebug net panel - basically all the resources load with 200 OK, and then there are no more new entries on the log, but the Firefox loading spinner continues to spin and the bottom of the page still says "transferring"..

Comment: @JoeM.  Try disabling firebug and using fiddler and see if you have any pending requests.  Its possible firebug is done transferring and the spinner is just hanging there.  Firebug can be buggy like that from time to time.  If all else fails Wireshark, will tell you all the network traffic you are getting.

Comment: MGotta love commentless downvotes a year or so later!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a very nice Firefox extension called [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) which is a bit easier to use than wireshark and friends

It lets you see the HTTP calls made by the page in much greater detail, and also the flow between pages (fast redirects and such). Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I installed the extension but it looks quite similar to the firebug net panel. How if possible would I use this extension to determine what file is still "transferring" even when the page appears to be finished loading (and the firebug net panel shows all resources finished)?

Comment: I assume that the **Time** field in the table will not have a value yet in this case.. If you see a value under Time, and you actually see the full content in the **Content** tab, I believe you can safely assume that the transfer is over. Unlike the firebug net panel, this extension never stops recording, even when you refresh or change pages, you won't lose your capture.

Comment: All of the resources show a value under "time".. as far as I can tell the full "content" is also showing under the "content" tab, but images do not display as images there correct? So I couldn't really tell if all of the images are showing the full content. Do you see the same thing if you click the link I included in my post? (firefox only) - all the resources seem to load fine but the spinner keeps spinning! Can't figure out how to see what is supposedly still transferring.

Comment: on my Chrome the spinner stops as it should. In FF the image spinner in the middle stops, but the top tab spinner indeed continues.. I'll look into it

Comment: I tried to check with Wireshark and with HTTPScoup (a different tool), and the conclusion from both was that all the data arrives successfully and no connection remains open with your server's IP. The problem in FF I think is related to something else

Comment: @talkol - please tell me what are the things that only fiddler can do, but chrome developer tools cannot do.