# Debugging why PHP Website stops responding to firefox

Tags: php, firefox

A Website, written in PHP and located elsewhere, loads fine in the 5 major browsers most of the time.

Sometimes in firefox the site does not load, but instead the contacting-server-icon dot rotates counter clockwise for what feels like forever. There does not seem to come an error message. I delete all cookies and the cache and restart firefox and try again but there is still the same behavior.

At the same time it works in other browsers on the same computer and also with firefox on another computer.

Using ping there does not seem to be packet loss.

How can I debug this problem?

The website is [stock.mrfootage.com](http://stock.mrfootage.com)

Edit:

While loading, a site cookie gets updated and the site title displays in the tab bar.

If I at the same time disable javascript and remove all cookies or all cookies related to the site and then reload, it works. I can then reenable javascript and use the site as normal again.

If on the other hand I only disable javascript or remove the cookies, the firefox tab still seems to hang on loading.

It might also be related to Firefox on Mac OS X, since the three computers where it didn't work were all macs and the two computers where I did not have this problem were running windows.

The Livehttpheaders add-on did not show any headers at all for this problem.

Comment: When you restart firefox trying checking your Process Explorer and make sure it is completely shutdown and there are no other firefox.exe processes running (assuming you are on windows). If you have php code that is getting stuck in a loop the session with that browser is still open until the process is completely shut down.

Comment: PHP does not interact with Firefox directly: PHP runs on the server, Firefox is the client / user agent. Firefox is not causing the error (unless you switch code depending on the user agend), the code itself is probably buggy. You could use the Firefox plugin "Live Http Headers" to have a first clue at which point the communication gets stuck and then do some logging around these events in your PHP-code. Also, keep in mind that JavaScripts is executed directly in the browser, so that might be another source to cause an error.

Comment: I know PHP runs on the server. But if that process is still running on the server and you hit that same process with your browser your not going to get a response until it ends or you start a new session. With firefox it won't create a new session until you completely close the browser. Clearing cache doesn't work.

Comment: what's the link for the website, let people here check with their own browsers

Comment: Yep, but the browser is only a consumer of your application, it doesn't affect its functionality. If there is no heavy computing along the response of your application, there is no way a specific browser could cause one. Actually, your applicatio is requested via HTTP, which is a well defined protocol spoken by all internet browsers. As I said, unless you run browser-specific code, there is absolutely no way an HTTP-request from Firefox would behave differently from an HTTP-request made with e.g. Chrome, because the `GET`-Method is idempotent and safe by definition, so it has no side effects.

Comment: Also, I think there is no 'sometimes' in coding - either it works or it doesn't. If it appears to be working 'sometimes', there must be some specific circumstances under which your application crashes or some edge cases you might not have thought of.

Comment: Do you have any ajax calls that run onload or immediately?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: BTW, it's better to use CSS for styling, instead of inline styles, many instances of `BGCOLOR` and the `font` element.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I know, I am helping them with an old site developed by someone else, but it would be a lot of work to change all of that at once. We do those improvements a little at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the problem is with HTML validation - meaning some of your HTML code isn't valid (like unclosed tags, tags in incorrect places, etc).

To figure this out, you can use an online HTML validator like http://validator.w3.org/ which will show you your problems. When you fix them, the website should load without problems.

Chances are, though, that the validator will show hundreds of problems and you won't want to fix all of them. In this case, you can find the problem spots in your HTML by deleting half of it and seeing if it loads (without getting stuck on the loading animation). Keep deleting parts and bringing them back until you locate the spot that causes this - and then figure out what's wrong with it.

To all the skeptics saying Firefox only validates once all HTML has been downloaded, this is incorrect. Bugs in the Firefox HTML parser are known to cause this behavior as evident from this [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304471/firefox-sits-on-transferring-data-from-or-read) and this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383811).

Comment: That shouldn't stop a browser from displaying a page at all. Moreover, the OP writes that it works in Firefox on other computers.

Comment: Different versions of Firefox are sensitive to different validation problems. This isn't an exact science since handling validation errors usually isn't standardized. Some will even consider these bugs in the parsing engine.

Comment: As @MarcelKorpel said HTML validation is done after all the html is downloaded from the server. The spinning indicator lets you know it is still trying to connect to the server or is downloading. So that may cause the page not to display properly but it wouldn't cause it to have a connection issue.

Comment: sorry buddies, but you are wrong. This happened to me before, and also happened to the guy in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304471/firefox-sits-on-transferring-data-from-or-read

Answer (score 0):

You could have some javascript that gets into an infinite loop and causes the interpreter to freeze.

Are you requiring 3rd party assets such as web-fonts, Javascripts, stylesheets? If you are, most likely one of these resources isn't loading and because it's synchronously handled (unless you have an asynchronous loader) the page won't display until the resource responds with either a timeout or an HTTP status code, etc.

Try loading the web page in Chrome or Safari with the inspector open to the Network tab. You'll see any connection errors there.